Python bot can’t be deployed to azure web app
I have python app flask bot developed in visual studio code with respective requirements.txt and template/index.html, debugged and locally works ok, created Linux azure web app and when I’m trying to deploy via viz studio code or GitHub deploy is with success but unable to run the the bot, receiving application error. Tried multiple times without success…
e # application.py
import os
import sys
import logging
from typing import Tuple, Optional, List, Dict
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
import openai
from datetime import datetime

# Initialize Flask application
application = Flask(__name__)

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    handlers=[
        logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout),
        logging.FileHandler('app.log')
    ]
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Config:
    """Configuration management class"""
    # Azure Search Configuration
    SEARCH_SERVICE = os.environ.get('SEARCH_SERVICE', 'searchmitkoman')
    SEARCH_KEY = os.environ.get('SEARCH_KEY')
    SEARCH_INDEX = os.environ.get('SEARCH_INDEX', 'vector-1730871636072')
    CONTENT_FIELD = 'chunk'
    SOURCE_FIELD = 'title'

    # Azure OpenAI Configuration
    AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT = os.environ.get('AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT')
    AZURE_OPENAI_KEY = os.environ.get('AZURE_OPENAI_KEY')
    AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT = os.environ.get('AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT', 'deployment_four')

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls) -> bool:
        """Validate required environment variables"""
        required_vars = ['SEARCH_KEY', 'AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT', 'AZURE_OPENAI_KEY']
        missing_vars = [var for var in required_vars if not getattr(cls, var)]
        if missing_vars:
            logger.error(f"Missing required environment variables: {', '.join(missing_vars)}")
            return False
        return True

# Initialize OpenAI client
openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_base = Config.AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT
openai.api_version = "2023-05-15"
openai.api_key = Config.AZURE_OPENAI_KEY

def perform_search(query: str) -> Tuple[Optional[str], Optional[List[str]]]:
    """
    Execute search using Azure Cognitive Search
    
    Args:
        query (str): Search query
        
    Returns:
        Tuple[Optional[str], Optional[List[str]]]: Content and references
    """
    try:
        endpoint = f"https://{Config.SEARCH_SERVICE}.search.windows.net"
        credential = AzureKeyCredential(Config.SEARCH_KEY)
        client = SearchClient(
            endpoint=endpoint,
            index_name=Config.SEARCH_INDEX,
            credential=credential
        )
        
        results = list(client.search(
            search_text=query,
            select=f"{Config.SOURCE_FIELD},{Config.CONTENT_FIELD}",
            top=3
        ))
        
        if not results:
            logger.warning(f"No results found for query: {query}")
            return None, None
            
        content = "\n".join([f"{doc[Config.SOURCE_FIELD]}: {doc[Config.CONTENT_FIELD]}" 
                           for doc in results])
        references = list(set([doc[Config.SOURCE_FIELD] for doc in results]))
        
        return content, references
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Search error: {str(e)}")
        return None, None

def generate_answer(conversation: List[Dict[str, str]]) -> str:
    """
 
@application.route('/health')
def health_check() -> tuple:
    """Health check endpoint"""
    status = {
        "status": "healthy",
        "timestamp": datetime.utcnow().isoformat(),
        "config_valid": Config.validate()
    }
    return jsonify(status), 200

@application.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index() -> str:
    """Main application route"""
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            prompt = request.form.get('prompt', '').strip()
            if not prompt:
                return render_template('index.html', error="Please enter a question.")

            # Validate configuration
            if not Config.validate():
                return render_template('index.html', 
                                    error="Application configuration error. Please contact support.")

            # Perform search
            content, references = perform_search(prompt)
            if not content:
                return render_template('index.html', 
                                    error="No relevant match data found.",
                                    prompt=prompt)

            # Generate answer
            conversation = [
                {"role": "system", "content": """You are a football analysis assistant specialized in Premier League matches. 
                Analyze the provided match data and give clear, concise insights about team performance, scores, and results. 
                Base your analysis only on the data provided."""},
                {"role": "user", "content": f"""Based on the following football match data:

{content}

Question: {prompt}

Please analyze this data and provide insights about the matches, including:
- Match results and scores
- Team performance
- Notable statistics

Please base your analysis only on the data provided."""}
            ]
            
            response = generate_answer(conversation)

            return render_template('index.html',
                                prompt=prompt,
                                response=response,
                                dataset_info=references)

        return render_template('index.html')
        
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in index route: {str(e)}")
        return render_template('index.html', 
                            error="An error occurred. Please try again.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Only for local development
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))


Please provide code what you have tried?

provided in the main thread removed only content of this function: def generate_answer(conversation: List[Dict[str, str]]) -> str:

I have this error in the logs: 2024-11-09T09:13:41.164Z ERROR - Container botwebapp_0_42d2e224 for site botwebapp has exited, failing site start
2024-11-09T09:13:41.252Z ERROR - Container botwebapp_0_42d2e224 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

Use this python3 -m aiohttp.web -H 0.0.0.0 -P 8000 app:init_func command in your Azure Web app->Configuration ->startup command.

Or Use this command gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 application:application.

I tried it is not working, it is strange because the deployment is ok, locally also is ok....

Provide your GitHub repo link if possible.

Follow below steps to deploy a Python bot application to Azure:

Create a Bot and Azure App Service.
Create a client secret in the automatically created App registration to use it as Microsoft App Password.
Update the Microsoft App ID and Password in config.py.

class DefaultConfig:
    """ Bot Configuration """

    PORT = 3978
    APP_ID = os.environ.get("MicrosoftAppId", "Microsoft_APP_ID")
    APP_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("MicrosoftAppPassword", "<Microsoft_App_Password>")

Enclose the route with a function as below:
def init_func(argv):
    APP = web.Application(middlewares=[aiohttp_error_middleware])
    APP.router.add_post("/api/messages", messages)
    return APP
if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = init_func(None)

    try:
        web.run_app(APP, host="0.0.0.0", port=CONFIG.PORT)
    except Exception as error:
        raise error

Deploy the webapp to Azure.
Bot Configuration:

Add App Service's domain as Messaging endpoint in Azure Bot's configuration.


Use gunicorn command to run the deployed Bot.
Use below command if you have init_func() as mentioned above:
python3 -m aiohttp.web -H 0.0.0.0 -P 8000 app:init_func

Bot=>Test in web chat:


Navigate to Log Stream under App Service=>Monitoring and check for the detailed errors regarding the issue.

Open KUDU site of the web app and check if the Application folder is available in Site/wwwroot folder.


